# Using a void pointer to an array to multiply matrices

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply matrices in C. The multiply function also calls dot product function. Below are the functions and the 3 errors I get:

```
char dotProduct(void *A, void *B, int N, int i, int j) {
    char result;

    while(i < N - 1) {
        while(j < N - 1) {
            result += A[N * i + j] * B[N * i + j];                 // error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'void')

            j++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}

void multiply(void *A, void *B, void *C, int N) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
            C[N * i + j] = 0;                                     // error: incomplete type 'void' is not assignable 

            for(int k = 0; k < N - 1; k++) {
                C[N * i + j] += dotProduct(A, B, N, i, j);        // error: subscripted value is not an array , pointer or vector
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what these errors mean. For instance, "subscripted value is not an array , pointer or vector": It is an array, I don't know why I can't do that operation. Also, the other 2, I don't understand what they mean. Could someone please elaborate?

Comment: How do you multiply two voids? Why are you even using voids? Why are you using char as result?

Comment: @kingW3 I'm using voids because I don't the type of the array being passed

Comment: You don't _what?_ the type of the array being passed? There is a verb missing in your sentence (You don't _know_?) `void` is `void`, you can't have `void a;` variable, and `void*` type if a generic pointer - it's not a pointer, not an array and not a vector (there is no such think as vector in C). You can start by studying `qsort` function implementations on how C programs are written to handle generic types.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `void`, you're going to also need to pass the stride of the array, otherwise the spacing of the elements isn't known.  If you're using 8, 16 or 32 bit floats (or integers) you'd need to express this, otherwise the compiler has no idea what the spacing is between elements and doesn't know how far in memory a pointer increment should be.  Even if you pass in a stride, the compiler has no idea what you mean when you multiply two `void`.

If I were doing this in C, I'd probably write typed version out, or emulate C++ templates like this:

```
#define DEFN_DOT_PRODUCT(TYPE, suffix) TYPE dotProduct##suffix(TYPE *A, TYPE *B, int N, int i, int j) { \
    TYPE result = 0; \
    while(i < N - 1) { \
        while(j < N - 1) { \
            result += A[N * i + j] * B[N * i + j]; \
            j++; \
        } \
        i++; \
    } \
    return result; \
}
DEFN_DOT_PRODUCT(int, i);
DEFN_DOT_PRODUCT(float, f);
DEFN_DOT_PRODUCT(double, d);
#undef DEFN_DOT_PRODUCT

/* use */
dotProducti(/* whatever */)
```